# Algorithm for seasonal trends

Tags: data-mining

I have a very big table with lots of names and how much they are searched by date.

I would like to find trending patterns. When does a name rise and when does it fall. Without knowing the name or the pattern before.
The rise could be during the seasons of the year but also during a week.

Like a 'warm hat' is trending in winter and falling in summer.
Or searches for a "board game" might rise on Sunday and decrease on Monday.

The table looks simplified like this:

```
winter gloves, 2014-01-01, 200
warm hat, 2014-01-01, 300
swimming short, 2014-01-01, 1
sunscreen, 2014-01-01, 2
....
winter gloves, 2014-07-01, 1
warm hat, 2014-07-01, 1
swimming short, 2014-07-01, 200
sunscreen, 2014-07-01, 300
```

Which algorithms should I have a look at?

Thanks for any hint,
Joerg

Answer (score 1):

As you are handling with time series data and you want to find trends; A good approach should be consider applying [Holt-Winter's seasonal method](https://otexts.com/fpp2/holt-winters.html). This algorithm handle seasonal, trend and smooth parameters. A good implementation of this kind of algorithm is [Prophet by Facebook](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#r-api). You can code an exploratory analysis with this library and obtain trend, yearly seasonality, and weekly seasonality of the time series, among other components. Example:

[image]